# Transforming a bound on vectors from unit cube back into $\mathbf R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two vectors $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$:

$$\mathbf v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\y_1\\z_1\end{pmatrix}, 
\mathbf v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}x_2\\y_2\\z_2\end{pmatrix}$$

If I transform the vectors so that they are in the unit cube $[0,1]\times[0,1]\times[0,1]$:

\begin{align}
\mathbf v_1' = \begin{pmatrix}x_1'\\y_1'\\z_1'\end{pmatrix}, 
\mathbf v_2' = \begin{pmatrix}x_2'\\y_2'\\z_2'\end{pmatrix}\\
x_1',y_1',z_1', x_2',y_2',z_2' \in [0,1]
\end{align}

Then I know that the following bound is valid:

\begin{align}
|x'_2 - x'_1| &\le \epsilon\\
|y'_2 - y'_1| &\le \epsilon\\
|z'_2 - z'_1| &\le \epsilon\\
\end{align}

The transformation is achieved through:

$$\mathbf v'_i = \left(\frac{1}{N}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x_i\\y_i\\z_i\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}\right)\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$

where $N=\max\left(||\mathbf v_1||,||\mathbf v_2||\right)$

Is there a way I can transform the bound $\epsilon$ back so I have a bound on e.g. $|x_2-x_1|$?

For example, if I can calculate the maximum distance between $\mathbf v_1'$ and $\mathbf v_2'$ as $\sqrt3\epsilon$, how would I know the maximum distance between $\mathbf v_1$ and $\mathbf v_2$?